# How to get a result from a collection on MongoDB using FastAPI?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, fastapi

I'm trying to create an API using FastAPI and MongoDB that has just a `GET` method and I have no clue for how to do this.
My application already populated the MongoDB with a huge data base using an txt file that is converted to csv and include all data on MONGODB collections and what I'm trying to do is: Give a zip code in the endpoint route(e.g. `localhost:8000/cep/123456789`) and my application will return all information from my MongoDB collections that is part of that zip code like street, city.

```
@app.get('/cep/{cep}')
def find_ceps():
    mongo_uri = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/")
    db_name = mongo_uri["cep4free"]
    col = db_name["cep4free"]

    for i in col.find({}):
        return i


cep = find_ceps()
return cep
```

I tried to do this, but it isn't work and I have no idea how to return this using a `GET` method.
I'm just new on Python and FastAPI as well and I'm coding this API for practice and learn. I would be glad if anyone could help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is separate out your db initialization from your actual route. FastAPI shows an [example of how to do that](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/nosql-databases/), just replace the Couch initialization lines with the ones you need for Mongo.

Second, you (usually) will have a `database` folder with code you'll be using in your route. This is part of a [layered architecture approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#what-are-layers). From here you'd either define a schema, or just call a method from the defined class in the data layer you just created.

For example (of the more simplified approach) we would call `cep_db.findAll()` in the route. This method could live in a class named `Cep` in the file `database/cep.py`.

Finally, see this project https://github.com/markqiu/fastapi-mongodb-realworld-example-app for a working example.